# SQL report performance on large data sets

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, report

I am looking to migrating LiDAR data (approximately 4 billion records) into a SQL Server 2008 database, then create a report that will allow users to get the LiDAR data within their area of interest.

There will be only 3 columns `X, Y, Z`. Does anyone have experience with this size data and is it feasible to run queries on this size of data? Or am I going to run into issue with timing out?

Comment: What datatype are those columns? How "selective" are each of those columns? What kind of queries are you going to be running against this data set? How many rows out of those 4 billion will each query return?

Comment: After reading the wikipedia article on LiDar I am now an expert, so I guess you have one enormous set of x/y coordinates with the measured depth (z) against them. This starts to give us a clue for your workload, which I guess would be lots of BETWEENs on the X and Y columns, then retrieving the Z value. My gut feel is this would be perfect for a columnstore (SQL 2012/14), particularly since I guess you would load this data once and never update it afterwards. Lastly... can you confirm whether you will simply store one map or lots of different maps?

Comment: Hi Nick you are correct about the nature of the data.  What I am hoping to achieve is that a person can extract the x,y,z data for an area of interest to then import into GIS software package and create a digital elevation model (DEM).  How big the area extracted will depend on users needs.  All the data collectively covers two areas of approximately 7000km2